# Parse CSV file from Advanced Custom Fields 'file' field

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, advanced-custom-fields, fgetcsv

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for wordpress to allow a user to upload a CSV file.  I then need to get the data from that CSV file.  I know I need to use fgetcsv() php function, but I am having trouble.

I can print the object like this:

```
$file = get_field('location_info');
print_r($file);
```

which gives me

```
Array ( [id] => 8 [alt] => [title] => locations [caption] => [description] => [mime_type] => text/csv [url] => http://lc.something.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/locations.csv )
```

So how can I get the data out of that csv file using PHP.

I am currently trying:

```
$file = get_field('location_info');
$filecontents = fgetcsv($file);
```

But that give me the error "

```
Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /var/www/websites/metromont/app/wp-content/themes/metromont/page-contact.php on line 7"
```

How do i get the 'resource' out of this?

Comment: [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) expects a resource.  You can try to use the `url` like this `$file = get_field('location_info')['url'];`

Comment: Tried that but got the same error message.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the same error message since adding `['url']` would have pulled a string value - can you update your code and error message?

Answer (score 0):

**[Fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)** function expects this resource:

> **handle**
>
> A valid file pointer to a file successfully opened by [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [popen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php), or [fsockopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).

Try to use code snippet below for getting CSV contents:

```
$file = get_field( 'location_info' );

if ( $file ) {
  if ( ( $handle = fopen( $file["url"], "r" ) ) !== FALSE ) {
    while ( ( $data_row = fgetcsv( $handle, 1000, "," ) ) !== FALSE ) {
      $num = count( $data_row );
      for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data_row[ $c ] . ", ";
      }
       echo "<br />";
    }
    fclose( $handle );
  }
}
```

**Output sample data:**

> id, first_name, last_name, email, gender, ip_address,
>
> 1, Philip, Evans, pevans0@hugedomains.com, Male, 8.106.111.3,
>
> 2, Raymond, Matthews, rmatthews1@cdbaby.com, Male, 165.36.29.127,
>
> 3, Kathy, Lawrence, klawrence2@usda.gov, Female, 17.23.224.247,